# an, in oder an der Straße

Tags: word-choice

An/in oder an der Straße?

Zu welchem Fall passt jedes Wort?

Wie ist es richtig zu sagen:

1.Ich bin gerade an/ auf  ... Straße.

2. Ich bin gerade an/ in 12 ... Straße (wenn damit eina Haus gemeint)
3. Es liegt an/in ...Straße
4. Es liegt an/in 12 ...Straße
5. Ich wohne an/in ...Straße

6.ich wohne an/in 12 ...Straße

Comment: Meinst du mit _12 ... Straße_ einen Straßennamen und eine Hausnummer?

Comment: At least related [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/20194/1696).

Answer (score 8):

Eigentlich sind alle angegebenen Fälle möglich, bedeuten aber ggf. etwas leicht unterschiedliches.

> Ich bin gerade an der ...straße

Ich stehe gerade an der Fahrbahn der Straße.

> Ich bin gerade auf der ...straße

Ich fahre/laufe gerade auf dieser Straße.

> Ich bin gerade in der ...straße

Generell bewege ich mich gerade zwischen Anfang und Ende dieser Straße.

> Ich bin gerade an/in 12 ... Straße (wenn damit eina Haus gemeint)

Das sagt man im Deutschen so nicht. Die korrekte Formulierung wäre im Deutschen:

> Ich bin gerade an/bei/in der ...straße 12.

Hier gilt: `an/bei`, wenn man gerade dort vorbeigeht oder vor der Tür angekommen ist und `in`, wenn man wirklich auch reingegangen ist.

> Es liegt an/auf/in der ...straße

`An`, wenn etwas am Rand der Straße liegt. Das kann ein Gegenstand sein, der dort liegt (z.B. ein Ball liegt an der ...straße) oder auch ein Gebäude, das an die Straße angrenzt.

`Auf`, wenn der Gegenstand wirklich auf der Fahrbahn liegt.

`In`, wenn man von einer Örtlichkeit spricht, die sich in dieser Straße befindet. Beispielsweise: `Der Metzger ist in der Bahnhofstraße`.

> Es liegt an/in 12 ...Straße

Wiederum: Dies sagt man im Deutschen so nicht (siehe oben).

> Ich wohne an/in der ...straße

Üblich ist `in`. Man kann `an` verwenden, um beispielsweise die Nähe zu einer Örtlichkeit auszudrücken. Beispielsweise:

> Ich wohne an der Autobahn A5
>   Ich wohne an der Fußgängerzone

Und wiederum:

> Ich wohne an/in 12 ...Straße

Das sagt man im Deutschen nicht. Man würde sagen:

> Ich wohne in der ...straße 12.