# probiere auf (Dativ) dieser Nummer ODER probiere auf diese Nummer

Tags: sentence-structure

Was ist korrekt?

> Probiere auf diese Nummer?

oder

> Probiere auf dieser Nummer?

bzw.

> Probiere auf dem Handy

oder

> auf das Handy?

Warum?

Comment: Can you provide more context? Maybe provide the original sentence (if it's in English). None of those is correct right now, but at least in the  second example, more context is needed, both version could be possible. [See also here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20194/example-with-prepositions-auf-an-and-bei?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to say is "(Please) try this number." For example "That's an old business card and that number doesn't work anymore. Please try this number if you want to get in touch with me." Similarly "Please try my cellphone if you can't reach me on my home phone. I'm pretty sure none of the phrases you listed have this meaning in German. If you want to try something *on* a cellphone then you can use *auf* with dative. For example

- *Hast du es auf seinem Handy probiert?* -- "Have you tried it on his cell phone?" (From "Weeds" 2007, subtitles via DWDS).

Comment: "Auf" with dative can be used to denote a location, not only in the sense of "on top of sth.": "Sie ist auf dem Rathaus, um den Antrag abzugeben" or "Er arbeitet auf dem Bau". See [the Duden entry for 'auf', meaning 1. a)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_Praeposition). I'd assume this use has been transfered to "locations" in a more figurative sense: "Du kannst ihn auf Rufnummer 123-4 erreichen" or, as in the example, "Du kannst ihn auf dem Handy erreichen".